# Custom page layout html editor borders?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I have a PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField on my page layout. When editing the page. The html editor has no borders, so it is hard to realise. How can i have borders around the html editor.

Thanks

Comment: any ideas about the problem?